# A word for the section of a resume that includes sports and plays

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a section on the resume that includes the sports teams I've played on and the plays that I've acted in.

What is a good term for this section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Extracurricular activities"** is the usual term. A good term for such a section, however, largely depends on who you are, your profession and who is going to receive your resumé.  If it's a job application and your artistic and sportive experience are totally unrelated to the position you're applying for, I suggest **"trivia"**

> - [**extracurricular activity**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Extracurricular+activities) - educational activities not falling within the scope of the regular curriculum
> - [**"trivia"**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trivia) -  Insignificant or inessential matters; petty details or considerations, trifles.